# Disable highly verbose logging

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, logback

I am getting this highly verbose logging and I want to get rid of it.

```
1:39:20.187 [main] INFO  c.v.c.c.ConfigManager - End XML Read
11:39:20.187 [main] INFO  c.v.c.c.ConfigManager - The content of ConfigCfg_pdMetering.xml is ConfigCfg [xxx=yyy]
11:39:37.335 [Thread-1] DEBUG o.a.h.c.p.RequestProxyAuthentication - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
11:39:37.335 [Thread-1] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultHttpClient - Attempt 1 to execute request
```

The logging comes from a jar I have imported in the project. I modified the logback.xml and log4j.properties in the jar using  "jar uf"

logback.xml now looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration debug="false">
      <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
          <!-- encoders are by default assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder -->
          <encoder>
              <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
          </pattern>
          </encoder>
      </appender>
      <logger name="com.hccl" level="ERROR"/>
      <logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="ERROR"/>
      <root level="debug">
          <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
      </root>
  </configuration>
```

and log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received=ERROR

log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing=ERROR

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%p [%c{3}] %m%n

log4j.logger.httpclient.wire=ERROR
```

I imported this modified jar and imported it to my project. This has not affected the logging.
Also I am getting the following in the console:

```
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

I do not know why I am seeing this warning.

Comment: What about the <root level="debug"> in the logback.xml? Have you tried to set it to INFO for example?

Comment: Tried with <root level="ERROR">, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

**Muting Apache http**

The packages you want to mute are `c.v.c.c.` and `o.a.h`. Those are abbreviations. Also, you specified `<logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="ERROR"/>` which doesn't match the above (take the first letters of each package name).

You might have more luck with

```
<logger name="org.apache.http" level="ERROR"/>
```

to shut down all org apache http logging (which is probably `o.a.h.*`).

**Muting `c.v.c.c`**

To mute the first two lines beginning with `c.v.c.c.ConfigManager`, you need to find out the classes. You can do this either by replacing `%logger{36}` with just `%logger` to have the full package and class name printed. Or perhaps it's your own class. In this case you can just putt a corresponding logger entry into your file by yourself.

**Warning for slf4j-Binding**

If slf4j outputs warnings about "actual bindings", you have probably more than one slf4j binding in your classpath. As I read from your question, you try to use both logback and log4j, which won't work - slf4j decides to use logback only. Remove log4j and the log4j.properties. If they get included by maven dependencies, specify exclude tags for those dependencies.

Comment: The logging framework is shortening the long package names, you should still configure for the full package name.